# Alternative to writing many files. MongoDB?

Tags: linux, mongodb, perl, file, database

I have a Perl script that produces ~10000 files in the 1kB - 10kB size area, which is not optimal for performance, so I though about using MongoDB instead of writing the many files. I need to run the script on my laptops Linux and OSX.

**Question**

Would MongoDB be overkill? Or are there something more suited for this sort of local file storage?

Comment: What problems are you running into when dealing with 10,000 files? How do you intend to use the data within the files?

Comment: What is your Perl script doing? Show it or at least explain in details what you want it to do and why so many files!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some file systems are better than other to deal with dozen of thousands of small files. According to rumors, BTRFS or ReiserFS used to be better than Ext3 or Ext4. And you could set up the block size (perhaps to 1Kbyte) when making the file system.

You could stay with 10K files, but it might be easier to put them in hundred directories, i.e. have `dir01/file000.txt dir01/file999.txt dir02/file000.txt`... `dir02/file999.txt`  .... `dir99/`  ....

<sup>It is at least more human friendly -so `ls` gives a reasonable output-, and may be more efficient on some old filesystems.</sup>

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), like [MariaDb](https://mariadb.org/) (or *MySQL*) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) are database *servers*, so you need to have the server running (perhaps just on `localhost`) and the sole client server connection has some cost.

You could also consider [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/), which is a *library* providing indexed files.

And you could also consider [Sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), which is also a *library* providing an Sql database.

At last, 10K files of 10Kbytes each is only 100Mbytes. This fits easily in memory, or in a single file...

<sup>And keeping 10K files of 1 to 10Kbytes each can have advantages, e.g. if content is textual: standard tools like `grep` or `awk` work well on them.</sup>

It really depends upon your application.